# Is there any way to import templates in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, import, layouts, template

I have tried to find info on how to import a template for layout in ArcMap. I have a template file pagx file. In Pro there is import by the insert tab, but not in ArcMap. Is there a solution for ArcMap?

Answer (score 2):

The mapx, pagx, and lyrx formats are not backward compatible with ArcGIS Desktop, they are new file formats, so their technology is too recent to be read by the ArcMap product. Even the files saved using ArcGIS Pro 2.0 cannot be opened by previous versions of ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Templates in ArcMap are MXD files placed in particular folder locations.

In much older versions there were MXT files for templates but nowadays the only MXT file is the Normal.mxt used to initialize ArcMap.

PAGX files are for ArcGIS Pro.